# How to get a char from an ASCII Character Code in C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding, ascii, escaping

I'm trying to parse a file in C# that has field (string) arrays separated by ASCII character codes 0, 1 and 2 (in Visual Basic 6 you can generate these by using Chr(0) or Chr(1) etc.)

I know that for character code 0 in C# you can do the following:

```
char separator = '\0';
```

But this doesn't work for character codes 1 and 2?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Two options:

```
char c1 = '\u0001';
char c1 = (char) 1;
```

Comment: What about char sep = '\x32'; ?

Comment: @ngoozeff: I dislike `\x` for various reasons, and wouldn't suggest using it.

Comment: LOL - It makes me depressed to give you even MORE points Jon, but thanks for the answer anyway :P

Comment: Probably clear to everyone - but just to be explicit. In the first option in this answer the number is the character code in hexidecmal. in the 2nd option it is a decimal. Obviously 1(decimal) = 1(hex) but for higher codes it isn't! eg: `char c = '\u0021'` is equivalent to `char c = (char)33` is equivalent to  `char c = '!'`

Comment: try this System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string c);

Comment: @NaveedKhan: No, that won't help. This isn't about HTML encoding or decoding.

Comment: yes you are right but this will going to convert every asci code within a string

Comment: @NaveedKhan: Not in the way that the question is about.

Answer (score 42):

You can simply write:

```
char c = (char) 2;
```

or

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(2);
```

or more complex option for ASCII encoding only

```
char[] characters = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[]{2});
char c = characters[0];
```

Comment: Given that we're talking about two specific values which are less than 128, the latter option seems unnecessarily long-winded. Unicode was designed to match ASCII.

Comment: It's good if you want to convert more than 1 byte or an array.

Answer (score 30):

> It is important to notice that in C# the **char** type is stored as Unicode UTF-16.

### From ASCII equivalent integer to char

```
char c = (char)88;
```

or

```
char c = Convert.ToChar(88)
```

### From char to ASCII equivalent integer

```
int asciiCode = (int)'A';
```

The literal must be ASCII equivalent. For example:

```
string str = "Xสีน้ำเงิน";
Console.WriteLine((int)str[0]);
Console.WriteLine((int)str[1]);
```

will print

```
X
3626
```

Extended ASCII ranges from 0 to 255.

### From default UTF-16 literal to char

Using the Symbol

```
char c = 'X';
```

Using the Unicode code

```
char c = '\u0058';
```

Using the Hexadecimal

```
char c = '\x0058';
```