# C# Count each uppercase letter, and each lowercase letter

Tags: c#, string

Hi so I have some homework, the goal is to count how many words there are, spaces there are, and uppercase and lowercase letters. But whats confusing me is the output has to show each and ever individual letter A-Z a-z and have a number next to it showing how many times it occurs. I really dont understand this at all past where I am in my code. I am only taking this class so I can do Cisco Networking and so I didn't have to do Calculus. I'm never going to program after this semester. And have been stuck at this for 4 hours. any help would be appreciated.... even if you could help me understand the concept of how to do this? thank you.

I have conjured this up

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int countedWords = 0, count = 0;  //Declaring integers to be used 

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a string\n");
            string inputString = Console.ReadLine();

            countedWords = inputString.Split(' ').Length; //counts words
            Console.WriteLine("\nREPORT FOR: " + inputString + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("WORDCOUNT: " + countedWords);


            foreach (char c in inputString)  //counts number of uppercase letters
            {
                if (Char.IsUpper(c))
                    count++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly Calculus.  :)

Comment: Yeah, I dont plan on doing ANYTHING related to C# in the IT industry

Comment: Im not asking for the answers in code form. just an explanation in LAYMANS terms that is understandible by a n00b

Comment: I figured it out! thank you for the input. got 25/25

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework - I'll give you a clue.

Since you want a count of every possible letter, you might want to consider thinking of this problem in terms of *grouping* instead of iterating and counting.  This can be handled via [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx).

Comment: I looked at your link at that really does make no sense to me, Let me state again that I know NOTHING about programming and my teacher is useless he is rated 1 out of 5 on rate my proff .com

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is to create an array of 26 (or 52) ints, initialize them all to 0 and each time you see the appropriate letter, you increment the appropriate bucket. You can put this into the existing `foreach`.

For display, you would just iterate through your array and print the letter that it stands for and the number of instances of that letter.

Comment: I have thought of that possibly, but so much coding. Is there any loop methods that can accomplish the same thing?

Comment: You already have the necessary loop (your `foreach`). You would just want to add an additional comparison/increment step inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Make a struct with 
Alphabet

1. Alphabet
2. Count

Make lists out of it, ListUpper, ListLower, ListSpace, ListOthers.
Load the list as you encounter the elements appropriately and display when you are done.

Won't write the code for you :)

Comment: Literally that is like chineese to me

Comment: my teacher has never mentioned or showed us List... functions...

Comment: they guy teaches java and constantly is complaining about teaching c#

Comment: Probably should stick with arrays. If I were implementing this on my own, I'd use something different, but I know how intro classes are, and they prefer you to stick with more basic data types.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start for you.

First i would put each of your declarations onto a new line as well as making them words that pertain what it is being used for(if its a counter for lower cases make the variable called lowerCase_Count etc) IMO since it's generally considered a good practice and makes it much much easier to read your code and make comments as to what each variable or object does.

Next if i understand what you wrote correctly he is looking for this code to display a count of every: Capital letter, Lower case letter, space(does this just me white space or , : etc?), and word. Also he wants a list of how many times each letter appears in the given text.

what you had was a good start and i added some more to your foreach loop as seen below:

```
  using System;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declaring integers to be used 
            int countedWords = 0;
            int cap_count = 0;
            int lower_count = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a string\n");
            string inputString = Console.ReadLine();

            countedWords = inputString.Split(' ').Length; //counts words
            Console.WriteLine("\nREPORT FOR: " + inputString + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("WORDCOUNT: " + countedWords);


            foreach (char c in inputString)
            {
                //if is upper case add to cap_count
                if (Char.IsUpper(c))
                    cap_count++;
                //if char is a punctuation or white space ignore it else 
                // add as lower case
                else if (!char.IsPunctuation(c) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                    lower_count++;

            }

            //display results.
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Letters: " + (cap_count + lower_count));
            Console.WriteLine("Number of capital Letters: " + cap_count);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of lower case Letters: " + lower_count);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of spaces: " + (countedWords - 1));


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This should be a good starting point for you to complete the rest. I hope this Helps.

Comment: Wouldn't commas make the `lower_count` increment since they're neither Upper or Separators? I'm not a C# guy, but just asking.

Comment: Ah good catch. I hadn't tested it but the code above should work.

Comment: Thank you very much I am at school now and am taking a look to see if I can understand what youve done. Thank you for everyones input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another hint: Each character in the string has a numeric value, often called its ASCII value*. You can get the string as an array of `char`s by using `str.ToCharArray()`.

* *A note for completeness, in more detail than the original poster needs.* Strings in C# are actually stored as Unicode characters. But the first 128 characters of UTF-8 maps to the corresponding ASCII characters, so in this case, the difference doesn't matter much.

Comment: This post might come in handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648781/how-to-get-character-for-a-given-ascii-value

Answer (score -9):

```
Using system;
Using system.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int c = 0;
            int d = 0;
            int e = 0;
            int f = 0;
            int g = 0;
            int h = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            int l = 0;
            int m = 0;
            int n = 0;
            int o = 0;
            int p = 0;
            int q = 0;
            int r = 0;
            int s = 0;
            int t = 0;
            int u = 0;
            int v = 0;
            int w = 0;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int z = 0;

            int A = 0;
            int B = 0;
            int C = 0;
            int D = 0;
            int E = 0;
            int F = 0;
            int G = 0;
            int H = 0;
            int I = 0;
            int J = 0;
            int K = 0;
            int L = 0;
            int M = 0;
            int N = 0;
            int O = 0;
            int P = 0;
            int Q = 0;
            int R = 0;
            int S = 0;
            int T = 0;
            int U = 0;
            int V = 0;
            int W = 0;
            int X = 0;
            int Y = 0;
            int Z = 0;
            int readChar = 0;
            int word = 0;
            int lower = 0;
            int upper = 0;
            string inputString ="";
            char ch = ' ';
            string findString = "";
            int space = 0;
            int startingPoint = 0;
            int findStringCount = 0;


            Console.Write("Please enter a string: ");


            do{
                readChar = Console.Read();

                ch = Convert.ToChar(readChar);
                if (ch.Equals(' '))
                {
                    space++;
                }
                else if (Char.IsLower(ch))
                {
                    lower++;
                    if (ch.Equals('a')) 
                    {
                        a++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('b')) 
                    {
                        b++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('c')) 
                    {
                        c++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('d')) 
                    {
                        d++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('e')) 
                    {
                        e++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('f')) 
                    {
                        f++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('g')) 
                    {
                        g++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('h')) 
                    {
                        h++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('i')) 
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('j')) 
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('k')) 
                    {
                        k++;
                    }
                   else if (ch.Equals('l')) 
                    {
                        l++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('m')) 
                    {
                        m++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('n')) 
                    {
                        n++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('o')) 
                    {
                        o++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('p')) 
                    {
                        p++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('q')) 
                    {
                        q++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('r')) 
                    {
                        r++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('s')) 
                    {
                        s++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('t')) 
                    {
                        t++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('u')) 
                    {
                        u++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('v')) 
                    {
                        v++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('w')) 
                    {
                        w++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('x')) 
                    {
                        x++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('y')) 
                    {
                        y++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('z')) 
                    {
                        z++;
                    }
                }
                else if (Char.IsUpper(ch))

                {
                    upper++;
                    if (ch.Equals('A')) 
                    {
                        A++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('B')) 
                    {
                        B++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('C')) 
                    {
                        C++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('D')) 
                    {
                        D++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('E')) 
                    {
                       E++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('F')) 
                    {
                        F++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('G')) 
                    {
                       G++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('H')) 
                    {
                        H++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('I')) 
                    {
                       I++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('J')) 
                    {
                        J++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('K')) 
                    {
                        K++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('L')) 
                    {
                        L++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('M')) 
                    {
                       M++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('N')) 
                    {
                        N++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('O')) 
                    {
                        O++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('P')) 
                    {
                       P++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('Q')) 
                    {
                        Q++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('R')) 
                    {
                        R++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('S')) 
                    {
                       S++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('T')) 
                    {
                        T++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('U')) 
                    {
                        U++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('V')) 
                    {
                        V++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('W')) 
                    {
                        W++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('X')) 
                    {
                        X++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('Y')) 
                    {
                        Y++;
                    }
                    else if (ch.Equals('Z')) 
                    {
                        Z++;
                    }
                }

                if (((ch.Equals(' ') && (!inputString.EndsWith(" ")))||(ch.Equals('\r') && (!inputString.EndsWith(" "))))&&(inputString!=""))
                {
                    word++;
                }

                inputString = inputString + ch;

            } while (ch != '\r');

            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Report on {0}",inputString);

            Console.WriteLine("# of spaces {0}",space);
            Console.WriteLine("# of lower {0}", lower);
            Console.WriteLine("# of upper {0}", upper);
            Console.WriteLine("# of word {0}", word);
            Console.WriteLine("UPPERCASE");
            if (A >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A = {0}",A);
            }
            if (B >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("B = {0}",B);
            }
            if (C >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("C = {0}", C);
            }
            if (D >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("D = {0}", D);
            }
            if (E >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("E = {0}", E);
            }
            if (F >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("F = {0}", F);
            } if (G >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("G = {0}", G);
            }
            if (H >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("H = {0}", H);
            }
            if (I >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I = {0}", I);
            }
            if (J >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("J = {0}", J);
            }
            if (K >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("K = {0}", K);
            }
            if (L >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("L = {0}", L);
            }
            if (M >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("M = {0}", M);
            }
           if (N >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("N = {0}",N);
            }
            if (O >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O = {0}",O);
            }
            if (P >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("P = {0}",P);
            }
            if (Q >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Q = {0}",Q);
            }
            if (R >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("R = {0}",R);
            }
            if (S >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("S = {0}",S);
            }
            if (T >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("T = {0}",T);
            }
            if (U >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("U = {0}",U);
            }
            if (V >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("V = {0}",V);
            }
            if (W >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("W = {0}",W);
            }
            if (X >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("X = {0}",X);
            }
            if (Y >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Y = {0}",Y);
            }
            if (Z >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Z = {0}",Z);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("LOWERCASE");
            if (a >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("a = {0}", a);
            }
            if (b >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("b = {0}", b);
            }
            if (c >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("c = {0}", c);
            }
            if (d >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("d = {0}", d);
            }
            if (e >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("e = {0}", e);
            }
            if (f >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("f = {0}", f);
            } if (g >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("g = {0}", g);
            }
            if (h >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("h = {0}", h);
            }
            if (i >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);
            }
            if (j >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("j = {0}", j);
            }
            if (k >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("k = {0}", k);
            }
            if (l >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("l = {0}", l);
            }
            if (m >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("m = {0}", m);
            }
            if (n >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("n = {0}", n);
            }
            if (o >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("o = {0}", o);
            }
            if (p >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("p = {0}", p);
            }
            if (q >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("q = {0}", q);
            }
            if (r >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("r = {0}", r);
            }
            if (s >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("s = {0}", s);
            }
            if (t >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("t = {0}", t);
            }
            if (u >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("u = {0}", u);
            }
            if (v >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("v = {0}", v);
            }
            if (w >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("w = {0}", w);
            }
            if (x >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("x = {0}", x);
            }
            if (y >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("y = {0}", y);
            }
            if (z >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("z = {0}", z);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Write("Please enter a substring ");
            findString = Console.ReadLine();


            if (findString.Length <= inputString.Length)
            {
                do
                {
                    if (inputString.IndexOf(findString, startingPoint) != -1)
                    {
                        findStringCount++;
                        startingPoint = inputString.IndexOf(findString, startingPoint) + findString.Length;
                    }

                } while (inputString.IndexOf(findString, startingPoint) != -1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Substring is too long!");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The number of times that {0} is found in the text is {1}", findString, findStringCount);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1. Worst. Possible. Solution. There is almost no way you could choose a less effective way.

Comment: Are you paid per line of code?