# How to get value of escape characters in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to know the ASCII value of an escape sequence in runtime. for example:

```cs
string x = "\\b";
char res = someFunctionCall(x);
//res = '\b' = 0x08
```

The difference here that I only know x at runtime.

I know that this can be made with simple switch (already doing that), but I was wondering if it can be made using some existing c# call. I tried `Char.Parse(x)`, but it didn't work.

---

**Edit**: I'm not talking here about converting '\b' to its corresponding ASCII value, rather, I'd like to parse "\\b" as what you write in c# to get '\b'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get character for a given ascii value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648781/how-to-get-character-for-a-given-ascii-value)

Comment: @BugFinder: I don't see how it's a duplicate of that at all.

Comment: easiest way is to use dictionary. look here and make dictionary out of that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: Fundamentally, this is language-specific. The escape sequences for (say) VB or F# could be very different to the escape sequences for C#.

So the first thing you need to do is scope the problem. A switch can help for simple escape sequences, but handling `\uabcd` is going to be harder.

Comment: "\\b" is not an escape sequence but a literal two char string

Comment: @JonSkeet because if you take any individual character from a string you can return the value of it using that method - which seemed to be the question..

Comment: @BugFinder: No, the point is to map the string `@"\b"` to U+0008. How exactly do you expect to get that from the answer given there?

Comment: @BugFinder please read the edit.

Answer (score 1):

There is slow but rather easy way to do this. compile your code at runtime and let c# compiler take care of that! I know its overkill for what you want. but it works.

Anyway as @JonSkeet noted you can use a dictionary for simple escape sequences. take your list from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Here is solution by compiling code at runtime, Note that its VERY SLOW, so I suggest you to replace and map multiple characters at once so compiler only runs and evaluate all of that for you only once.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

//...

private static void Main()
{
    string x = "\\b";
    string res = Evaluate(x);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}

public static string Evaluate(string input)
{
    // code to compile.
    const string format = "namespace EscapeSequenceMapper {{public class Program{{public static string Main(){{ return \"{0}\";}}}}}}";

    // compile code.
    var cr = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(
        new CompilerParameters { GenerateInMemory = true }, string.Format(format, input));

    if (cr.Errors.HasErrors) return null;

    // get main method and invoke.
    var method = cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType("EscapeSequenceMapper.Program").GetMethod("Main");
    return (string)method.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: I would call this the laziest problem solution in stackoverflow :D

Comment: @mohRamadan I think that fulfills `someFunctionCall` :)