# Escape codes for control characters in C# string

Tags: c#, ms-word, control-characters

I want to find the codes for the below control characters used in Microsoft Word.

[image]

I have found some of them. Please correct me if I am wrong.
I have browsed the web for them. But I was unable to find some of the codes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414900/how-to-get-a-char-from-an-ascii-character-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: Some of them just don't have escaped codes. You'll have to create a `char` with their numeric value

Comment: If they all have an ASCII code this thread might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414900/how-to-get-a-char-from-an-ascii-character-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/ might help too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The list of available escape symbols is this one, from [What character escape sequences are available? (by Jon Skeet)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/):

```
\' – single quote, needed for character literals
\" – double quote, needed for string literals
\\ – backslash
\0 – Unicode character 0
\a – Alert (character 7)
\b – Backspace (character 8)
\f – Form feed (character 12)
\n – New line (character 10)
\r – Carriage return (character 13)
\t – Horizontal tab (character 9)
\v – Vertical quote (character 11)
\uxxxx – Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxx
\xn[n][n][n] – Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value nnnn (variable length version of \uxxxx)
\Uxxxxxxxx – Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxxxxxx (for generating surrogates)
```

If the one you need isn't directly available as a simple escape code, you can use the hexadecimal escape. In your case, for example, `\x0E` for 14 or `\x15` for 21. **As stated in Jon Skeet's comment: it's better to use the Unicode version, i.e. `\u000e` and `\u0015`.**

Comment: I'd personally recommend avoiding using `\x` as it's variable-length in a very confusing way. I'd suggest `\u000e` and `\u0015`.